# How to PREVENT php from converting special characters in a string

Tags: php, special-characters, domdocument

I have a PHP script that adds a p element with text to an HTML file from a form using the DOMDocument class.  The text area may contain new line symbols but since browsers ignore these in HTML markup its outputting the text inside the p element as one big mash of text.  I'd like to convert the new line symbols to br so when I insert the string into my html document the browser parses it as a new line.  I've tried a str_replace function, which doesn't work.

I'm thinking I could search for occurances of the new line character in the string and then use the DOMDocument createElement method to create a new br element at every occurance, but is there an easier way?

I've tried using

```
$bodytext = nl2br($_POST['bodytext']);
```

and then when I use the createElement method

```
$pelement = $webpage->createElement('p', $bodytext);
```

it converts the new line characters in $bodytext to the special characters equivelant to the <br /> tag, which when rendered by the browser ends up as literally <br /> in the text, not a new line.

Answer (score 1):

It's already a function, check it out:

https://www.php.net/nl2br

You may also want to check out *htmlspecialchars()*

Comment: That only gets me halfway there.  That function used when I get the variable from the form

$bodytext = nl2br($_POST['bodytext']);

ends up inserting special characters into my html doc, rather than the element itself.  The result when the page is rendered in the browser is the literal rather than the browser interpreting it as a tag... if that makes sense.

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure that I follow. What appears in the browser? You can literally read <br /> as part of the text on the page?

Comment: that's correct Dan I can literally read the <br/> tag as part of the text on the browser, that's because it converts the actual <br/> to the special characters (&lt;br /&gt;) which get inserted into my html file.